# How to configure .htaccess file to allow inject style and script?

Tags: .htaccess, content-security-policy

I have an API which is using below .htaccess file

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set Content-Security-Policy  "default-src 'none'"   <-----This Line-------
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"

<Files "composer.json">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
<Files "composer.lock">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)              %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php
```

And I want to load an html file to which is inject some script and style from local files. And the line I specified above prevent this.

What is the way to exclude that html file?

You can see the error I'm having

[image: console-error]

Comment: I completely fail to understand what you are trying to do. Please invest some time into revising your question so that others can understand what it actually is you are trying to do. That configuration has nothing to do with "injection" (as far as I can say). And that last rewriting rule does not really make sense in my eyes (`RewriteRule ^(.+)              %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php`).

Comment: @arkascha Actually, it has nothing to do with it `RewriteRule` and other lines.  I have an html file, I want to render it with php. However, the .htaccess line I mentioned above, prevents me from injecting these files from an external URL. How can I exclude this address?

Comment: So you actually simply mean "load" when you write "inject"? OK. Although I fail to understand why you need to load styles in an API... Anyway, I would again suggest that you _revise_ your question, so edit it instead of adding additional information in comments.

Comment: And once more: that rewriting rule is funny. Usually one uses the `REQUEST_FILENAME` variable to test, if a physical file exists. The http server maps that into the folder of the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` by itself. And you should rewrite to `/index.php`, not to an absolute path, because the http server needs to map that again. Actually I am surprised that this works at all.

Comment: Replace the `Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'"` by `Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' unpkg.com"; img-src 'self'"`. This will fix errors you shown, but `'unsafe-inline'` in the `script-src` is very insecure. Or just remove `Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'"` line if you are not ready to configure CSP properly.

Comment: @arkascha I wrote a swagger documentation for API. I was just trying to render a HTML file that has some CSS and js in it. But CSP was preventing load those files. And thanks for the tip about `RewriteRule ` you're right I'll fix that line.